# How to specify a certain place in a (CDS) weather data query?

Tags: meteorology, reanalysis, python, era, netcdf

I am trying to get time series data for a specific place (latitude and longitude) for different weather elements from the CDS datapool. Therefore, I am using the cdsapi package and can run queries such as:

```
import cdsapi
import xarray as xr

# settings
filename = "here.nc"

# request
c = cdsapi.Client()
res = c.retrieve(
    "reanalysis-era5-single-levels",
    {
        "product_type": "reanalysis",
        "variable": "2m_temperature",
        "year": "2019",
        "month": "01",
        "day": "01",
        "time": [
            "00:00",
        ],
        "format": "netcdf",
    },
    filename,
)

nc = xr.open_dataset(filename, decode_cf=False)
df = nc.to_dataframe().reset_index(drop=False)
print(df)
```

This can easily be extended to more time points, but not as easily to places (even the returned latitude and longitude coordinates sometimes do are unreasonable).  If I understand correctly the netcdf data is already interpolated, but there is no parameter to specify a distinct place (only area and grid). Because I have to query several places all over the world and want to go a few years back with hourly/daily resolution, querying large grids will not work.

Does anybody have an idea how to get the data for a specific place? If possible, I would like to keep my tooling Python only, but happy to use other packages or try other solutions.

Comment: @NB_Coder You need to specify the area - I have included an example in this answer https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/16588/extracting-regional-data-from-era5/16621#16621